# Unicode in Python on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unicode, non-ascii-characters

I need to make a POST request in which the data might be non-ascii (chinese, japanese characters).
I need to convert the input to unicode and encode with utf-8. Here's how I did it:

```
foo = unicode(self.request.get('foo'), 'utf-8') #convert to unicode
foo = foo.encode('utf-8')                       #encode with utf-8
data = {'foo': foo}
payload = urllib.urlencode(data)
```

However, I keep getting this error in my logs:

> TypeError: decoding Unicode is not
>   supported

Comment: why are you decoding from utf-8 to encode again in utf-8?

Comment: i followed this guide: http://evanjones.ca/python-utf8.html

Comment: That guide does not tell you to decode from UTF8 to Unicode and then encode it back. For your further question (see below) I recommend you start a question where you state the problem you are trying to solve (not the detail, but the big problem), what you have tried, and why that didn't work.

Comment: all I want is to be able to make a POST request with non-ascii characters and I can't urlencode

Comment: Right, you can't urlencode unicode objects. As far as I know the formdata should be in UTF8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unicode can't be decoded because it's already unicode.

Try this instead:

```
if isinstance(var, str):
    var = unicode(var, 'utf-8')
else:
    var = unicode(var)
```

Comment: but I tried using normal ascii characters and the same error occured

Comment: @Ngo It's not about the characters, it's about the type of the string

Answer (score 1):

Ok some comments:

```
 foo = unicode(self.request.get('foo'), 'utf-8') #convert to unicode
```

Don't call it "convert". Call it "decode", it makes it clearer.

```
 foo = foo.encode('utf-8')                       #encode with utf-8
```

But why? You just decoded it *from* UTF8, why are you encoding it back? You can just as well do:

```
 foo = self.request.get('foo')
```

That's equivalent to the above two lines.

To lessen your confusion on Unicode, read this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: thanks for clarifying it. how do I urlencode non-ascii characters to form a payload for a POST request now?

Comment: this is how it is done on GAE http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.html

Comment: Oh, of course, the form, my bad. I thought you were talking about file uploads, I don't know why I thought that, my bad. I think form data should be in UTF8.

Comment: There is a valid purpose to a UTF-8 decode-encode cycle. It will ensure there are no UTF-8-invalid byte sequences in the string. In some cases invalid byte sequences, in particular overlongs, can be a security problem. It's often best to Unicode-decode all byte data at the input stage of an application, work with it as native Unicode strings, then encode to the required encoding when the data leaves your app, going into a byte stream.

Comment: It won't be a security problem in Python, and in this case that check should be done in the application that the request is sent to. But of course, on most cases you would do something with the data before sending it on, and in that case it should of course be decoded at the input stage.